# 6.5GB of internal storage is missing, how can I free it

Tags: internal-storage, htc-desire

I have a HTC Desire 510,
Android version 4.4.3, HTC Sence version 6.0 Software number 1.51.401.7 HTC SDK API level 6.25

When I go to storage I see:

- Apps 3.56GB
- Music 110MB
- Photos & videos 60.82MB
- Other 3.88GB
- Available 400MB

I want to make more internal memory available.
When Clicking on more space (or selecting apps from the settings menu)
I see:

- 7.59GB / 8.00GB
- Apps 1,21 GB
- Gallery 47.74MB
- Miscellaneous:  107MB

About 6.5 GB of memory use is not listed!

Does any one have an idea what that can be and how I can free it?

Extra information added on 2018-01-21 by request of: Izzy

I understand that the system also uses some internal storage.
The frustrating part is that the "missing" memory used to be less.

It seem something beyond my control is eating away internal storage.  I've followed the instructions at https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux to install adb and get the following result:

```
Filesystem            Size   Used   Free   Blksize
/dev                   432M   152K   432M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         432M     0K   432M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory: Permission denied        
/mnt/asec              432M     0K   432M   4096
/mnt/obb               432M     0K   432M   4096
/system               2479M  1611M   868M   4096
/data                 4091M  3646M   444M   4096 
/cache                 309M   256K   309M   4096
/devlog                 15M     9M     6M   4096 
/fataldevlog            15M     8M     7M   4096
```

I'm fine with a system needing 2GB for other stuff.
What amazes me is the 3.5GB for data when I only have a few small app's installed.
When I want to do an ls for /data I get permission denied.

I've used SD Maid Storage analyzer.
It tells me /storage/emulated/0 has 3.6GB used / 3.9 GB capacity.
Clicking on it gives me only 534MB used.
**More than 3GB is gone!**
I really want to have it back because I can hardly update any app let alone install new ones.

With regard to the .data directory:
There is one other directory in it with a dozen of files with sizes in KB's (not even in MB's)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts!  I've opened my answer with "the usual question". This is indeed almost a "frequently asked" one. See e.g.: [Is some of my internal memory missing?](/q/14683/16575) // [Why does my phone show less storage than it's supposed to?](/q/83323/16575) // [Why the Galaxy has 25GB instead of 32GB](/q/24304/16575) (here it's also 6.5G "missing") – just to give a few examples (many more exist AFAIR).

Answer (score 1):

The usual question. According to [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_510-6608.php), your device has 8 GB internal storage *altogether* – which is not only the `/data` partition (where your apps and user data are stored), but also includes the `/system` partition where the OS resides. Depending on manufacturer and device, the latter can consume up to 8 GB of your internal storage chip (usually devices with heavily modified GUIs such as Samsung's TouchWiz are the ones using the biggest sizes for that).

Though on a device with 8 GB altogether 6.5 GB for the `/system` partition sounds a bit much, that's the part excluded from your listings. To check how much is consumed by `/system` you can use a terminal app (or [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) shell) to run the `mount` or `df` commands (the latter gives easier to read output sufficient here).

In addition to the two mentioned partitions, there're also other partitions consuming some space (e.g. `/boot` and `/recovery`), but they're usually rather small (much less than 100M in most cases) while not to be ignored in this context. For a full list, you can e.g. check with [this XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-510/development/criket-htc-desire-510-partitions-t3183281) (which unfortunately does not include sizes).

A more detailed discussion (also on the HTC Desire 510) can also be found [at AndroidCentral](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/467264-how-my-htc-desire-already-out-internal-storage.html), and give you additional clues.

Comment: @technetium May I suggest you integrate those 3 comments with your original question? There formatting will work again then as well, and the information gets readable. I vaguely remember some questions along the lines of [something is secretly eating my internal storage](/questions/27127/16575); this one is a trifle old but can serve as starting point (e.g. follow the questions in the "linked" and "related" section).

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. (Something else in my life had a higher priority) I've integrated my comments in the other directory. The only option in the question you link to that I did not try is a factory reset. I'd like to avoid that.